# Can I say "empower toward"?

Tags: grammar, idioms

This is a one line description about how I am trying to describe my work. However afraid the grammar is not correct and can't find anything about it on the web.

"Empowering teams toward efficient & pragmatic digitalization"

What do you recommend?

Thank you.

Comment: You empower someone (give them the power) to _do_ something, so I would recommend that you use a verb rather than a noun.

Comment: @Kate or to be something?

Comment: This sounds like a bunch of marketing buzzwords.  I recommend something entirely different.

Comment: I see, thanks all for your comments